# Issues with Inversion Count MergeSort Algorithm- Python

Tags: python, algorithm, mergesort, inversion

I am trying to count inversion from a file using MergeSort, and my code seems to work for smaller files, but bigger files produce the wrong output. My code:

InversionCount.py:

```
count = 0

def merge_sort_inversions(numberlist):
    if len(numberlist) < 2:
        return numberlist
    else:
        mid = len(numberlist) // 2
        lefthalf = numberlist[:mid]
        righthalf = numberlist[mid:]

    return sort_count_inversions(merge_sort_inversions(lefthalf), merge_sort_inversions(righthalf))

def sort_count_inversions(l, r):
    result = []

    i=0
    j=0

    global count

    while(i < len(l) and j<len(r)):
        if (r[j] > l[i]):
            result.append(l[i])
            i+= 1
        elif(r[j] < l[i]):
            result.append(r[j])
            count += (len(l) - i)
            j+=1
    if(j>=len(r)):
        result+=l
    elif(i>=len(l)):
        result+=r

    print(count)
    return result
```

Application.py:

```
import InversionCount

text_file = open('algorithms-1-test2.txt', 'r')
number_list = text_file.readlines()
number_list = list(map(int, number_list))

InversionCount.merge_sort_inversions(number_list)
```

The answer is: 2407905288 but the final printed count I get is: 22945388587258. I'd really appreciate any help on this, as I'm trying to learn algorithms on my own. Also, my issue happens with large files, so how would I debug an issue that only seems to occur with a very large input (I tried testing this with smaller inputs and it gives the right answers)? Thank you!